# Receiving CORS errors while trying to test uploading on storage emulator

Tags: azure, ng-file-upload, azure-storage-emulator

I am trying to test the upload functionality for an html5, angularjs application using the azure storage emulator.  For some reason, everytime I send the file to the azure generated url for localhost I keep getting CORS errors.  Now on the cloud instance, I have used the following code to add CORS support and it works:

```
blobServiceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule()
{
    AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
    //ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() {"*"},
    AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Post | CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Delete,
    AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "http://example.com" },
    MaxAgeInSeconds = 3600
});
```

When I try to run this for the emulator I receive errors indicating this is not allowed.  Do I have to set up CORS for the emulator as well and if so how would I have to do this as the above code did not work from the emulator?

Comment: When and where is this piece of code running?

Comment: WebApiConfig, I have two separate solutions, one for the web side and one for the web api project.  The main problem is that I keep gtting the CORS errors while testing from the emulator.

Comment: I am not getting them in the cloud when I publish the web project just on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I wanted to clarify, as per MSDN documentation

> "Azure storage services support Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)
>   for the Blob, Table, and Queue services. The File service supports
>   CORS beginning with version 2015-02-21."

And further to that

> You can set CORS rules individually for each of the storage services, by calling Set Blob Service Properties, Set File Service Properties, Set Queue Service Properties, and Set Table Service Properties. Once you set the CORS rules for the service, then a properly authenticated request made against the service from a different domain will be evaluated to determine whether it is allowed according to the rules you have specified.

So I am curious if the service is a File service or just a blob service, you seem to have enabled CORS for the blob service as per the provided code snippet. But you did not put the code snippet for the upload function, if you are doing it via AJAX, you need to set header type to blob-type of Azure service else a cross origin request may be blocked at the requester end itself if it cannot match with the service response header type.

Do check these two links as well

[Windows Azure Service CORS example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Azure-Storage-CORS-45e5ce76)

[CORS for Azure Storage Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535601.aspx)